# cannot mock function in useEffect when toMatchSnapshot in Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm trying to get all snapshot on my **LayoutDummy.js** to complete my unit test coverage

when I Run Test I got error, it says dummyFunc is not a function like below

[image]

I have wrote my actual code in functional component and testing file like this

LayoutDummy.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const LayoutDummy = () => {
  const [caption, setCaption] = useState('loading...');
  useEffect(() => {
    dummyFunc();
  }, []);

  const dummyFunc = () => {
    setCaption('dummyFunc is running');
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <p>LayoutDummy</p>
      <p>{caption}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LayoutDummy;
```

**test**/LayoutDummy.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import ShallowRenderer from 'react-test-renderer/shallow';
import LayoutDummy from '../LayoutDummy';


const dummyFunc = jest.fn();

useEffect.mockImplementationOnce(fn => fn());

describe('mock func in useEffct', () => {

  test('render', () => {
    const shallow = new ShallowRenderer();
    const tree = shallow.render(<LayoutDummy />);
    dummyFunc.mockReturnValueOnce('dummyFunc is running');
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Why the function cannot mock in my unit test, please if there is any suggest to pass test with all snapshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is specific to React test renderer rather than `toMatchSnapshot`

`dummyFunc` cannot be mocked. `dummyFunc` variable is local to `LayoutDummy` function scope. Local variables cannot be accessed outside the scope where they were defined.

The test fails because `useEffect` works differently in test renderer rather than in DOM renderer. Normally `useEffect` callback would be called after the initial render but in tests it's called instantly before evaluating `const dummyFunc` line. There's no reason for this line to be specifically placed after `useEffect`. In order to not cause problems in tests it should be lifted:

```
  const [caption, setCaption] = useState('loading...');

  const dummyFunc = () => {
    setCaption('dummyFunc is running');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    dummyFunc();
  }, []);
```