# Can not access 'fetchSomeData()' before initialization

Tags: reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs

I am new in react unit test case. my all test are failing.

```
    React.useEffect(()=> {
     if(condition1&& condition2) {
      fetchSomeData();  
     }
   })
```

I have created one function for avoiding duplication but if I am running test file its failing all test
and giving error.

> Can not access 'fetchSomeData()' before initialization

Please let me know why this error coming .

Comment: this is pretty odd, as long as `fetchSomeData()` is defined, this seems to me more like `linter` error.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's very specific to the component and how exactly it's tested but you provided no information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64165739/cannot-mock-function-in-useeffect-when-tomatchsnapshot-in-jest